# Why did many odd-toed ungulates become extinct?

Tags: zoology

There were a lot of odd-toed ungulate animals in the ancient times but now just few of them survived. What is the reason for that?

Comment: I edited the question somewhat. You need to provide some more details such as how many/what fraction of odd-toed ungulates got extinct. Compare it with other group such as even-toes ungulates. Because a lot of species perish during selection event. When saying a lot of *group-A* organisms perished you should mention *with respect to what*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two suborder under perissodactyla that are still suvival, Hippomorpha and Ceratomorpha. many perissodactyla species become extinct may bacause the member of perissodactyla animals have sample stomach, compared with artiodactyla, so after the plant change on the earth, they cannot adapt it. and also hinting was one part of reason. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd-toed_ungulate

Comment: If you downvote an answer (or question for that matter) please leave a comment with an explanation. Users cannot improve their posts without some feedback.

Comment: @user137 I am not downvoting but I have to admit that the answer is grammatically wrong, badly linked and hard to understand